# passing a variable to XSLT from .vb file - without XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xslt

How to pass the constant variable to xslt , here I hard coded the college name in the xslt, but I don't want to do that way instead I want to pass that college name "CollegeName" as string.

```
< xsl: template match="/">
   < xsl:for-each select="Analysis">
   <html>
  <body>
  <table>
  <tr>
            <td width='100%' class='subLogo'>Rowan-cabarrus Comm College</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

.VB file

```
Dim CollegeName as Constant = Rowan-cabarrus Comm College
```

Dim reader As New XmlTextReader(New System.IO.StringReader(xmlstring))

```
    reader.Read()
    Dim objXSLTransform As New XslCompiledTransform()
    objXSLTransform.Load(xsltFilePath)
    Dim htmlOutput As New StringBuilder()
    Dim htmlWriter As TextWriter = New StringWriter(htmlOutput)
    objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, Nothing, htmlWriter)
    reader.Close()
    Return htmlOutput.ToString()
```

Comment: Can you include your current XSLT in your question (or at least a sample what uses the hard coded college name). More importantly, can you show the VB.net that is currently performing the XSLT transformation? It should be fairly straight-forward to amend it to pass parameters. Thanks!

Comment: added the xslt in the main question

Comment: Can you also please show the VB.net that is currently performing the XSLT transformation? Thank you.

Comment: added the vb.net code in the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass parameters to an XSLT stylesheet you can use the [XSLTArgumentList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 Dim argList as XsltArgumentList = new XsltArgumentList()

 argList.AddParam("CollegeName", "", "Rowan-cabarrus Comm College")
```

Then the `argList` is used as a parameter in the call to `Transform`

```
objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, argList, htmlWriter)
```

And in your XSLT, you just need to define a correspond parameter using `xsl:param`, which should be added as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` element

```
<xsl:param name="CollegeName"/>
```

You can use this in the same way as any variable, with the `$` prefix

```
<td width='100%' class='subLogo'><xsl:value-of select="$CollegeName" /></td>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 for an example.