# bind value to xslt from vb.net variable value and not with xml value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xslt

I want to bind vb.net variable value to the **xslt** , i know only binding the **xml** value as

```
< xsl:value-of select="somevalue"/>
```

but how to bind the value to **xslt** when i have **vb.net** varible as

```
Dim somevalue as string="Ramesh"
```

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: This question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442477/passing-a-variable-to-xslt-from-vb-file-without-xml Please do not double-post.

Comment: Ok Sir, I was waiting for the reponse there for a long time,still i am not able to add parameter to the xsltargumentlist

Comment: "*I was waiting for the reponse there for a long time*" That's no reason to waste other people's time.

Comment: sorry Martin , this wont get repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XSLT code you need to define a global parameter as

```
<xsl:param name="my-param"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="$my-param"/>
```

then in your .NET code when you run the transformation you can do

```
Dim xsltArgs As New XsltArgumentList()
xsltArgs.AddParam("my-param", "", "Ramesh")
```

and then when calling the `XslCompiled`'s `Transform` method pass in the `xsltArgs`, as in

```
Dim xsltProc as New XslCompiledTransform()
xsltProc.Load("file.xsl")
xsltProc.Transform("input.xml", xsltArgs, Response.Output)
```